# Get x11 frame window by class

Tags: xorg, xdotool

I can use `xdotool search --onlyvisible --class <class>` to find a window by class, but it gives me only the client window. I want to get the window manager decoration window. That means the id that `xwininfo -frame` would give me, but I want to select it by class.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

I came up with this bash script which combines `xdotool search` and `xwininfo -children` (which also gives the parent).

```
#!/bin/bash
for CLIENT_ID in $(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class "$1"); do
    echo $(xwininfo -children -id $CLIENT_ID | sed -n 's/^ *Parent window id: \(0x[[:xdigit:]][[:xdigit:]]*\).*/\1/p')
done
```